# Allow asp.net mvc api call to access files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, security

In a asp.net mvc 5 site hosted on a windows 2012 server I have some static jpg files in a folder within the website folder structure (/Files/1.jpg etc.) that I would like an api endpoint (GetPicture) to be able to serve.

The api uses basic authentication with a Token in the Authentication header.

On my dev machine (vs2013, IIS Express) the api serves the jpg files just fine.

However, when I call the api endpoint (api/v1/GetPicture/5) on the test/production server I'm getting the a 500 http code (UnauthorizedAccessException) and the error message: "Access to the path xxx is denied".

The user is being authenticated in the api call.

The api call:

```
GET https://app.domain.com/api/v1/GetPicture/5 HTTP/1.1
Host: app.domain.com
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 49
Authorization: Token 506b38df-947e-45a8-b2a0-49aa01e9a6f9
```

The api end point:

```
[Route("GetPicture/{id:int}")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetPicture()
{
    ...
    ...
    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
    result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = 
        new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") 
        {
            FileName = file.FileName
        };
    return result;
    ...
    ...
}
```

I'm guessing:
- that it is a IIS or file system security setup issue or
- that the pictures should be moved to the App_Data
- ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The IIS application pool identity isn't going to have access to any location on the hard disk.  so you can move the data under your c:\inetpub or give access to the app pool identity permission to access the directory.  Here's a link on appication pool identity http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Comment: The /Files/ folder is part of the web-site folder structure so the application pool identity should already have access to the files in the folder